# How to pass a Django Object to Javascript File (template buyed in envato elements)

Tags: javascript, python, django, mongodb

dears!!

I'm trying to get a Django object in a Javascript file.
My objective is to to connect a Django template to a Javascript file and render my model info in the website.

My models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(blank=True, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, verbose_name="Date")
    event_creation = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Creation", auto_now_add=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, verbose_name="Start")
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, verbose_name="End")
    event_updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Updated',auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'event_{self.title}'
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'event'
```

My serializers.py:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # _id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    channels = Event
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'
```

My views.py:

```
class Calendar(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = "calendar.html"
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer = EventSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)

    def get(self, request):
        context = {'event': self.data}
        return render(request, 'calendar.html', context)

    #FOR THE FUTURE: I WANT TO USE POST METHOD 
    # def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #     serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    #     serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    #     event = serializer.save()
    #     return Response({
    #         "event": EventSerializer(event, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
    #         "token": AuthToken.objects.create(event)[1]
    #     })
```

the Javascript file (I've detected that the object that render events on calendar are the one in commented lines. What I want is to pass my Django Object into that list, as these commented object, but using my models.py):

```
! function (v) {
"use strict";

function e() {}
e.prototype.init = function () {
    var a = v("#event-modal"),
        t = v("#modal-title"),
        n = v("#form-event"),
        l = null,
        i = null,
        r = document.getElementsByClassName("needs-validation"),
        l = null,
        i = null,
        e = new Date,
        s = e.getDate(),
        d = e.getMonth(),
        e = e.getFullYear();
    new FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable(document.getElementById("external-events"), 
    {
        itemSelector: ".external-event",
        eventData: function (e) {
            return {
                title: e.innerText,
                className: v(e).data("class")
            }
        }
    });
    e = [
    //         {
    //         title: "Pastel de Frango",
    //         start: new Date(e, d, 1)
    //     }, {
    //         title: "Calopsita",
    //         start: new Date(e, d, s - 5),
    //         end: new Date(e, d, s - 2),
    //         className: "bg-warning"
    //     }, {
    //         id: 999,
    //         title: "Papillon",
    //         start: new Date(e, d, s - 3, 16, 0),
    //         allDay: !1,
    //         className: "bg-info"
    //     }, {
    //         id: 999,
    //         title: "Kibe",
    //         start: new Date(e, d, s + 4, 16, 0),
    //         allDay: !1,
    //         className: "bg-primary"
    //     }, {
    //         title: "Quiabo",
    //         start: new Date(e, d, s, 10, 30),
    //         allDay: !1,
    //         className: "bg-success"
    //     }, {
    //         title: "Lunch",
    //         start: new Date(e, d, s, 12, 0),
    //         end: new Date(e, d, s, 14, 0),
    //         allDay: !1,
    //         className: "bg-danger"
    //     }, {
    //         title: "Birthday Party",
    //         start: new Date(e, d, s + 1, 19, 0),
    //         end: new Date(e, d, s + 1, 22, 30),
    //         allDay: !1,
    //         className: "bg-success"
    //     }, {
    //         title: "Click for Google",
    //         start: new Date(e, d, 28),
    //         end: new Date(e, d, 29),
    //         url: "http://google.com/",
    //         className: "bg-dark"
    //     }
    ]
    , document.getElementById("external-events"), d = document.getElementById("calendar");



 function o(e) {
            a.modal("show"), n.removeClass("was-validated"), n[0].reset(), v("#event-title").val(), v("#event-category").val(), t.text("Add Event"), i = e
        }
    var c = new FullCalendar.Calendar(d, {
        plugins: ["bootstrap", "interaction", "dayGrid", "timeGrid"],
        editable: !0,
        droppable: !0,
        selectable: !0,
        defaultView: "dayGridMonth",
        themeSystem: "bootstrap",
        header: {
            left: "prev,next today",
            center: "title",
            right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth"
        },
        eventClick: function (e) {
            a.modal("show"), n[0].reset(), l = e.event, v("#event-title").val(l.title), v("#event-category").val(l.classNames[0]), i = null, t.text("Edit Event"), i = null
            },
        dateClick: function (e) {
                o(e)
            },
            events: e
        });
        c.render(), v(n).on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            v("#form-event :input");
            var t = v("#event-title").val(),
                e = v("#event-category").val();
            !1 === r[0].checkValidity() ? (event.preventDefault(), 
        event.stopPropagation(), r[0].classList.add("was-validated")) : (l ? (l.setProp("title", t), l.setProp("classNames", [e])) : (e = {
                title: t,
                start: i.date,
                allDay: i.allDay,
                className: e
            }, c.addEvent(e)), a.modal("hide"))
        }), v("#btn-delete-event").on("click", function (e) {
            l && (l.remove(), l = null, a.modal("hide"))
        }), v("#btn-new-event").on("click", function (e) {
            o({
                date: new Date,
                allDay: !0
            })
        })
    }, v.CalendarPage = new e, v.CalendarPage.Constructor = e
}(window.jQuery),
function () {
    "use strict";
    window.jQuery.CalendarPage.init()
}();

Hope anybody can help me, I did'nt find any answer fo thatin ver.

Thankyou!!!
```

Comment: You can't pass the entire django object to the javascript. But you can assign the object field variables to java script variables in string format while displaying template like this: var title = {{ event.title }}

Comment: Thank you @SivaSankar, I will try to use this example in my template, hope it works!!